# Laptop's audio jack only works when bent at an angle

Tags: laptop, audio

My laptop's audio jack sends audio out no matter what. The problem is that if you plug it in, it sounds as if it's not sending "everything". I don't don't know to explain "everything" since I'm not an audio junkie. For example, there won't be any bass. Though, when I bend the headphone cord (the initial part that actually connected to the laptop) the audio changes. Sometimes, if I bend it the right way, I can get 100% audio. Sometimes, I have put something on the end of the audio cord to force it to bend.

I'm not sure if this is a permanent thing, so something I can fix. Is this a common issue? Can it be fixed?

EDIT1: I'm pretty sure that it's the laptop since I've used multiple headphones and have the same results. I use the same headphones on another laptop or iPod and it works fine.

EDIT2: It's good to note that this audio jack is used for both speaker and microphone.

Answer (score 4):

Try swapping the headphone out for another one - it really sounds like the cable is broken internally - If it isn't the headphone your jack itself is broken (which would explain the "Audio jack sends audio out no matter what" and the fact that jiggling it helps).

Forcing the cord to bend a certain way simply means you've bridged the contacts (for now) and that allows the cable to transmit things properly. If its the jack, its basically in just the right position that the broken jack connectors are touching your headphone connector.

Something is VERY definitely broken, somewhere.

Comment: If it is the laptop, how can I fix this if it is fixable?

Comment: Its not, short of soldering in a new one. You might be able to use an external one. I've not had issues using a TRRS jack with a TRS headphone so, that PROBABLY shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 4):

Once you rule out the headphones themselves, the obvious answer is that  the laptop's jack is damaged.

Rarely,  sound cards may allow you to use the microphone jack as a headphone jack; this would be a good solution. Failing that, your best bet is buying a USB sound card, or even better, a USB DAC with built-in headphone amplifier

Answer (score 2):

Several suspicions:

- First, which you've fairly well eliminated, is a broken wire in the headphone cable.
- Second is that the contacts in the jack have become bent and no longer make contact unless the plug is twisted to one side slightly.
- Third is that there is a mismatch between the size of the plug and the size of the socket -- the standard size is 1/8" or 3.5mm, but there are a few other sizes, particularly 3/32" or 2.5mm and (rarer) a 4.4mm.  If either your plug or socket is (for some odd reason) "odd" this would do it.
- A final possibility is that the socket has come loose inside the computer and is either making poor contact with the circuit board or is preventing the plug from seating all the way.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem all the time (really frustrating).  There's a very good chance that the wire on the inside is bent or broken, meaning you only complete the circuit when you hold it there manually.  Your best option is probably just to replace the headphones.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle around with the advanced controls on ur laptop. (The speaker at the bottom right near the clock)
Look for a left to right setting in any of the sound bars. Chances are one or all(the master volume) setting are set to deliver only one side of audio.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, 3.5mm "phone" jacks are among the least reliable connectors ever used for audio. (The 2.5 mm variety is even less reliable. 6.35 mm or quarter-inch types are a little better.)

Adding a fourth pole (for a combined mic/headphone jack) only made them worse.

If you're not prepared to do board-level repair - and on a laptop motherboard, I wouldn't recommend it - just get a USB audio adapter, one with separate mic and phone jacks.